# Could the MAIN breaker be moved from top left (current place) to lower right side of this panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

[image]

Is it possible (and no I'm not doing it myself), to move the main breaker from top left, down to lower right side of this panel, to shorten the wires and clean it up a bit inside? I'm sure it's a stupid question, but I was curious. Thank you.

Comment: Not a stupid question.  As far as that panel is set up, it looks like the the main breaker could be placed anywhere, and the electricity will not care.  Unfortunately you need to go by the panel labels and code, which one of the experts will explain soon.

Comment: Work on main breaker usually(safe) requires the power to be turned off at meter or pole, most power companies have free power shutoff(once a year) if call before.

Comment: If you want to make it 'pretty' then do something about the cable going through a 2" KO with no bushing.

Comment: I suspect that the requirement for the main to be bolted down will limit moving it.  The fact that it has that "factory installed" sticker also trends towards "leave it the bleep alone" and it will look just as neat as can be when you put the cover back on the box.

Comment: Cable going through the 2" knockout has been removed, already. I felt the same way about it...... Simple enough......I was just curious if moving a main was something that could be done.

Comment: await word from one of our usual suspects, who will know for sure.

Comment: To clean up remove the torn up phase tape off feeder, not required in this application. To figure out if main breaker can be moved you might look for clues on panel door or other labels or search the catalog number online. It might boil down to location that you can fit the required securing bracket.

Answer (score 7):

In order to move that, the new site would need to be capable of accepting a tie-down kit. Not every site is, and back-fed main breakers must be tied down.  Also the labeling must be changed to match.

### Don't fix what isn't broken.

There is nothing wrong with this panel.  OCD can be a boon to electrical safety, but not in a panel so-called "cleanup".   That is just uninformed "neat freaking".   It's uninformed because there are many *better* subjects on which to exert ones picayune tendencies.  For instance:

- making sure every hot **and neutral** in the panel is long enough to reach any breaker space in the panel, so you have freedom to rearrange as your needs change.
- Making sure every screw is torqued down *to spec*. This is a big problem, that's why NEC 110.14 was added.
- Making sure GFCI protection is not done haphazardly (as is often the case), protects everything that should be protected, leaves alone what should not, and is not redundant with some circuits wasting GFCIs and others having too little.
- AFCI protection is present where desired and appropriate.
- Switches and outlets are screws not backstabs, and are torqued correctly.
- Any aluminum wire is on properly rated receptacles and torqued to spec.  For 15-20A outlets and switches, that means CO-ALR devices.

Comment: amen to that Harper... That panel looks pretty good except for the missing bushing at the center bottom. The only reason I could think of why the OP wanted to move the main breaker is to accommodate a generator manual transfer switch interlock. Why "clean up" in a panel that's always covered?  I don't get it .  That panel looks pretty good to start with. Curious.